# byzantinemusic package issue with BZ-fonts

Tags: music

I am trying to use this package called [byzantinemusic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/byzantinemusic). It says I need byzantinemusic package and BZ-fonts and run XeLaTeX engine. I have a problem with BZ-fonts. I downladed the BZ-fonts from [here](http://www.melodima.gr/index.php?pg=downloads&lg=en), and installed them on my system. Then in the preamble I defined the new font as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{byzantinemusic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{BZByzantina}
\begin{document}
\th{\iso}[\ne]
\end{document}
```

But I get an error that $ is missing. How can I make the byzantinemusic package work properly, and get the same results as in the documentation?

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output? Maybe there is an over all better approach to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The package just redefines `\ne` within the environment `byzantinemusic` the last part of the package is:

```
\newenvironment{byzantinemusic}{% enable the music-related versions
\let\kk\kkBMusic
\let\R\RBMusic
\let\oli\oliBMusic
\let\ke\keBMusic
\let\zw\zwBMusic
\let\boy\boyBMusic
\let\oy\oyBMusic
\let\pa\paBMusic
\let\ga\gaBMusic
\let\di\diBMusic
\let\nh\nhBMusic
\let\t\tBMusic
\let\tha\thaBMusic
\let\bm\bmBMusic
\let\kor\korBMusic
\let\red\redBMusic
\let\spa\spaBMusic
\let\p\pBMusic
\let\y\yBMusic
\let\g\gBMusic
\let\ela\elaBMusic
\let\s\sBMusic 
\let\met\metBMusic
\let\ne\neBMusic
\let\na\naBMusic
\let\n\nBMusic
\let\k\kBMusic
%\let\b\bBMusic
%\let\x\xBMusic
%\let\xx\xxBMusic
\let\gg\ggBMusic
\let\arg\argBMusic
\let\dia\diaBMusic
\let\tri\triBMusic
\let\ypo\ypoBMusic
\let\bar\barBMusic
\let\th\thBMusic
\let\syn\synBMusic
\let\ysyn\ysynBMusic
\let\ll\llBMusic
\let\l\lBMusic
\let\L\LBMusic
\let\pl\plBMusic
\let\lp\lpBMusic
\let\gp\gpBMusic
\let\pg\pgBMusic
\let\ppg\ppgBMusic
\let\gpp\gppBMusic
%
\let\II\IIBMusic
\let\ν\νBMusic
\let\νε\νεBMusic
}{% enable the original versions
\let\ll\lloriginal
\let\l\loriginal
\let\ne\neoriginal  
\let\arg\argoriginal
\let\th\thoriginal
\let\b\boriginal
\let\k\koriginal
\let\bar\baroriginal
\let\gg\ggoriginal
\let\L\Loriginal
}
```

(actually the last part resetting to the original versions does nothing as the group structure restores them anyway)

so you neeed `\neBMusic` or be inside the `byzantinemusic` environment.

Comment: Thanks. I used `byzantinemusic` environment, and the music notations are working fine now. However, I am still getting an error about `\ne` as `undefined control sequence` and it suggests using `\anapodohta` instead, which works, but the scaling and positioning is not right. I can read more about that in the documentation. Another thing, when I write non-Latin characters in the square brackets in `\th{\iso}[...]` nothing appears under the music notations. Is this a LaTeX thing or related to the byzantinemusic package?

Comment: @BlackMath sorry I had never heard of the package and haven't looked at the doc I just fetched the sty and one font to try your example  so I can't really tell you more

Comment: As a frequent user of MusiXTeX I am not familiar with the byzantine package, but a quick look at the documentation gave me the impression that \ne always is followed by a space and a letter. Maybe this is the 'missing $'.